# Send_data changes language issue Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When a click on the 'View CSV' link on my site the csv downloads but the content of the csv is in Chinese instead of English. How do I ensure the language of what I'm passing through the send_data function doesn't change? Thanks for your help!

I have the following function in my controller:

```
def get_data_visit
      @csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
        csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
      end
    send_data Iconv.conv('iso-8859-1//IGNORE', 'utf-8', @csv_string), filename: "something.csv"  
    end
```

And the following function in my view:

```
<%= link_to "View CSV", get_data_visit_admin_stats_path %>
```

Ie. `["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]` becomes `潲ⱷ景䌬噓搬瑡੡` and I would like it to stay in English.

Answer (score 0):

I had to ensure libre office was reading utf-8 (changed in a drop down), then it worked.